# $A.util.addClass not working on components that are inside aura:if

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

I have some buttons inside a component that are by default hidden, but are shown when certain event is received.

When I receive the event, I am using `$A.util.addClass()` and `$A.util.removeClass()` to remove slds-hide and add slds-show. But this is not working.

Markup:

```
<lightning:layout aura:id="modalSearch">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showModal}">
        <c:modal title="Test Modal">
            <aura:set attribute="left">
                <lightning:button  aura:id="leftCancelButton" variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.hideModal}" class="slds-hide" />
            </aura:set>
            <aura:set attribute="right">
                <lightning:button aura:id="rightCancelButton" variant="neutral" label="Cancel" value="modalSearch" onclick="{!c.hideModal}" class="slds-hide"/>
                <lightning:button aura:id="doneButton" variant="brand" label="Done" value="modalSearch" onclick="{!c.handleDone}" class="slds-hide"/>
            </aura:set>        
        </c:modal>
    </aura:if>
</lightning:layout>

<!--some code -->
```

> Controller: Here modal is made visible on click of a button:

```
showUploadModal: function( component, event, helper ) {
    $A.util.addClass('modalSearch', 'slds-show');  //Theses classes work 
fine
    $A.util.removeClass('modalSearch', 'slds-hide');//Theses classes work 
fine
    component.set( 'v.showModal', true );
}
```

Now after this modal is opened, after some action an event is thrown from other component and handled in this component helper as below:

> Helper, to show the already hidden buttons conditionally:

```
var leftCancelButton = component.find('leftCancelButton');
var rightCancelButton = component.find('rightCancelButton');
var doneButton= component.find('doneButton');
if($A.get("$Browser.isIPad")){
    $A.util.removeClass(leftCancelButton, 'slds-hide'); 
    $A.util.addClass(leftCancelButton, 'slds-show');
}
else{
    $A.util.removeClass(rightCancelButton, 'slds-hide'); 
    $A.util.addClass(rightCancelButton, 'slds-show');    
}
$A.util.removeClass(doneButton, 'slds-hide'); 
$A.util.addClass(doneButton, 'slds-show');
```

> Modal.cmp markup:

```
<div>
    <div class="slds-float--left">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.left}" var="action">
            <span class="slds-p-horizontal--x-small">{!action}</span>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-float--right">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.right}" var="action">
            <span class="slds-p-horizontal--x-small">{!action}</span>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this is due to the aura:if. However, can somebody please help what can be solution for this?

Comment: What is the value if showModal initially ? Please share few more lines of code

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : Please have a look now.  The showModal is by default false.

Comment: When the if is hiding the elements, it's like they don't exist so your code should set the showModal to true then add the classes. Try moving the set to the first line of the block above the add class

Comment: @Eric :  The "showModal" is made true initiatlly. Only after it is made true the code to add/remove class in helper is executed. I hope I got you right.

Comment: Even I am facing a similar situation the only difference is I am not able to add my custom defined CSS classes, whereas I am able to add remove SLDS classes under aura:if component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it in markup through what seems a juggle up of aura:if and aura:set:

```
<lightning:layout aura:id="modalSearch">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showModal}">
        <c:modal title="Test Modal">
            <aura:set attribute="left">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isIPad}">
                    <lightning:button  aura:id="leftCancelButton" variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.hideModal}" class="{!v.enableButtons ? '' : 'slds-hide'}"/>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:set>
            <aura:set attribute="right">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isIPad}">
                    <lightning:button aura:id="doneButton" variant="brand" label="Done" value="modalSearch" onclick="{!c.handleDone}" class="{!v.enableButtons ? '' : 'slds-hide'}"/>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.enableButtons}">
                            <lightning:button aura:id="rightCancelButton" variant="neutral" label="Cancel" value="modalSearch" onclick="{!c.hideModal}" />
                            <lightning:button aura:id="doneButton" variant="brand" label="Done" value="modalSearch" onclick="{!c.handleDone}" />
                        </aura:if>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:set>        
        </c:modal>
    </aura:if>
</lightning:layout>
```

Still the question of why add/remove class is not working is open.

Comment: You accepted this as the answer, but it appears like your question is still not answered.  I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: @dphil : Yes it is not yet answered, though i found a workaround for my problem. Not sure if this is still a valid problem, SF may have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is a old post. Hopefully, anyone still searching might see solution for this.

- $A.util.addClass
- $A.util.removeClass

**Both doesn't work, if aura:id is used inside aura:if in above conditions.**

Of course, aura:if does impact availability of that component and then can only be used in controller javascript for reference in general condition.